# Middle School detective series with two friends from early 2010s

Tags: identification-request

I read this series around 2013-2015.
It centered around two friends who had their own detective business.
I remember the second book in the series had had a picture of the characters on top of a train. And I believe the cover of the third book had one of the characters holding something over their face. I also remember in one of the books has a client pay for their detective services using a valuable old penny.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's *The Brixton Brothers Series* by Mac Barnett, published 2009-2012.
The cover of the third book, *It Happened on a Train* has children on top of a train, and the fourth book's cover might match what you remember as the third one's:

[image: book cover]

[image: book cover]

From the fourth book: *Danger Goes Berserk*:

> “It’s a penny,” said Steve. “Look, I wasn’t going to take the case for
> fourteen dollars and sixty-three cents, and I’m not going to take it
> for fourteen sixty-four.”
>
> Brody just laughed. “That’s not just a penny, Mr. Detective Man.
> That’s my mint-condition 1914-D penny, and it’s worth six hundred
> sixty-eight dollars and seventy-five cents.”

Comment: Yes this is it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about the specific cover art you mention, but this series sounds like it could be *[Encyclopedia Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopedia_Brown)*.

The main character, Encyclopedia Brown, is a ten year old boy who runs a detective agency out of his garage, and is often helped by his friend Sally Kimball.

Comment: I feel like the only matching bits are the detective work and that the expense is nominal (25 cents for Encyclopedia Brown).